# Add "informative text" to Alert if TextFields are empty

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement, nsalert

I am trying to code a NSAlert, that appears when when some NSTextFields are empty.
I have 3 NSTextFields and I would like to have a NSAlert that shows which TextField ist empty in a list. It´s possible for me to do it for one text field, but how can I code it that the empty NSTextFields appear in the Alert ? If one Textfield is empty in the Altert should stand "TextField 1 is empty". If Field 1 and 2 are empty there should stand "TextField 1 is empty" and in the second row "TextField 2 is empty".

Here is my code:

```
if ([[TextField1 stringValue] length] == 0) {
    NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Error"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"TextField 1 is empty"];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self.view window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }];
}
```

Comment: `NSMutableString *messageText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
if ([[TextField1 stringValue] length] == 0)
   [messageText appendString:@"Textfield 1 is empty"];
if ([[TextField2 stringValue] length] == 0)
   [messageText appendString:@"Textfield 2 is empty"];
//And so on.
if ([messageText length] > 0) //We put at least one message in it)
{
    //Show NGAlert with [alert setInformativeText:messageText];
}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would chain the if-statements to get the desired result.
Set up a empty string and check every textField one after another. Add the error line to the string if it is empty. Don't forget to add a line break after appending a string.

My words in code:

```
NSString* errorMessage = @"";

if ([[TextField1 stringValue] length] == 0) {
    errorMessage = @"TextField 1 is empty.\n";
}

if ([[TextField2 stringValue] length] == 0) {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"TextField 2 is empty.\n"];
}   

if ([[TextField3 stringValue] length] == 0) {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"TextField 3 is empty."];
}

if (![errorMessage isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Error"];
    [alert setInformativeText:errorMessage];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self.view window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }];
}
```

This way you get dynamic output depending on which `NSTextField` was empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information automatically by a notification.

- Assign the tags 1, 2, 3 to the text fields.
- Set the delegate of all text fields in Interface Builder to the class you want to display the alert in.
- implement this method

  ```
  - (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
  {
    NSTextField *field = [aNotification object];
    if ([[field stringValue] length] == 0) {
      NSInteger tag = field.tag;
      NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
      [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
      [alert setMessageText:@"Error"];
      [alert setInformativeText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextField %ld is empty", tag]];
      [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self.view window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {NSLog(@"Success");}];
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I have not tried that, but wouldn't this cause the alert to appear immediately?